# Time in Milliseconds

Tags: time, schedule

How does one retrieve current time in milliseconds? `now()` returns time in seconds.

I know that you can use `fc::time_point::now()` from `fc/time.hpp`, but that include does not seem to work in contracts.

Comment: I would like to see an example too, but it seems it should be possible via `eos/contracts/eosiolib/time.hpp` which has a `time_point()` operator in its `block_timestamp` class. This computes the time by multiplying `500`ms by the slot id, which increments each block.

Comment: Just realized you said milliseconds. I don't know if this would be possible in the smart contact, because determinism? Seconds work because blocks are clocked to 0.5s intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Dan Larimer himself when you asked in the EOS Developer telegram

current_time() returns time in microseconds (rounded to block time)

Comment: Yes, so essentially you can only get time at a resolution of 0.5s